# iphone predicate like thing in android

Tags: android, for-loop, predicate

Is there anything in android that is similar to iphone predicate. Actually I want to search something by querying an arraycollection or a hashmap. Is there any techinique to do so??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look at this example here on Stackoverflow:

[Java: Search in HashMap keys based on regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879807/java-search-in-hashmap-keys-based-on-regex)