# Remove Entries in hashmap using composite String key

Tags: java

I have hashmap 
Key is String composed of concatenation of 3 elements (element1+element2+element3)

```
String key=element1+element2+element3;
```

which is put in the hashmap

```
HashMap<String,Object> map=new Hashmap<String,Object>();
map.put(key,new Object());
```

i want to remove all the entries in the hashmap matching key having element2
if(key.contains("element2")) then remove that entry in hashmap.

How accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple way is to get [keySet()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#keySet--) from your map which

> Returns a Set view of the keys contained in this map. The set is
>   backed by the map, so changes to the map are reflected in the set, and
>   vice-versa.

So

```
yourMap.keySet().removeIf(key -> key.contains(keyPart));
```

Answer (score 5):

Hash map needs an exact key - accessing by a partial key is not possible, meaning that you would need to iterate all keys, check for match on `"element2"`, and remove elements as you go:

```
Iterator<Map.Entry<String,Object>> iter = map.entrySet().iterator();
while(iter.hasNext()){
     Map.Entry<String,Object> entry = iter.next();
     if (entry.key().contains("element2")) {
         iter.remove();
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

we could also use Pattern and Matcher functionality

```
    public class TestMatcher {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            Map<String, Integer> sampleData = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
            sampleData.put("data1data21data3", new Integer(1));
            sampleData.put("data1data2A", new Integer(1));
            sampleData.put("data1data3", new Integer(1));
            sampleData.put("data3", new Integer(1));

            TestMatcher tm = new TestMatcher();
            tm.printMatchKey("data2[A-Z0-9]{1}", sampleData);
        }

        public void printMatchKey(String regex, Map<String, Integer> data) {
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);

            Iterator<String> keyIterator = data.keySet().iterator();
            while(keyIterator.hasNext()) {
                String key = keyIterator.next();
                Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(key);
                if (matcher.find()) {
                    System.out.println("Key " + key + " contains " + regex);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879807/java-search-in-hashmap-keys-based-on-regex?answertab=votes#tab-top).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this.. A regex map which has regular expressions as its key so you wont need to iterate through all key value pairs yourself .. its a custom map implementation..

[Check Here](http://java.dzone.com/articles/regular-expression-hashmap)